# Get identical rows

Tags: awk

I have a file like this: (`data.dat`)

```
 1  1            1  1            1  1            1  1            1  1            1  1            1  1            1  1
 2  2            2  2            2  2            2  2            2  2            2  2            2  2            2  2
 3  3            3  3            3  3            3  3            3  3            3  3            3  3            3  3
 4  4            4  4            4  4            4  4            4  4            4  4            4  4            4  7
 5  5            5  5            5  5            5  5            5  5            5  5            5  5            5  9
 6  6            6  6            6  6            6  6            6  6            6  7            6  7           
 7  9            7  7            7  7            7  7            7  7            7  8            7  9         
 8 10            8  9            8  9            8  8            8  8            8  9                       
                 9  11           9  10           9  9            9  9            9  10                      
                10  12          10  11                          10  10          10  11
```

The odd columns are simple line counters (NR), the even columns are simple values. I would like to get those values, in which the second (or even) colum values are the same in all even columns, i.e. I should get this output:

```
1
2
3
9
```

I have already tried to make this line, but something is wrong:

```
awk '{arr1[$1]=$2;arr2[$3]=$4;arr3[$5]=$6;arr4[$7]=$8;arr5[$9]=$10;arr6[$11]=$12;arr7[$13]=$14;arr8[$15]=$16;}END{for(x in arr1) if(x in arr2 && x in arr3 && x in arr4 && x in arr5 && x in arr6 && x in arr7 && x in arr8) print arr1[x];}' data.dat | sort -n
```

Is there a better way, by the way?

**UPDATE:** The real problem is that the array indices are different. So, the arr[...] method does not work... :(

Comment: What is wrong, is the output wrong or do you get an error?

Comment: Ok, I know what is the source of problem: the odd columns have different number of rows... Nevertheless I do not know the solution for this... I am trying to edit my question according to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work -

```
awk '
BEGIN{x=0}
{if (x<NF) x=NF;for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) a[$i]++} 
END{x=x/2;for (y in a) if (x==a[y]) print y}' INPUT_FILE
```

#### Explanation:

1. We set a `variable x=0` in the `BEGIN` statement.
2. We use this `variable` to get to find out maximum number of fields (This is useful later).
3. We store value of every `second column` to an array and get their number of occurrences.
4. We divide the `variable x by 2` to verify maximum number a value can occur in every second column.
5. If the occurrences of numbers in an array matches this variable it means they are present in every second column.

#### Test: with your sample file

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk '
BEGIN{x=0}
{if (x<NF) x=NF;for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) a[$i]++} 
END{x=x/2;for (y in a) if (x==a[y]) print y}' file
2
3
9
1
```

You can either pipe the output to `sort -n` to get it in order or use this -

```
awk '
BEGIN{x=0}
{if (x<NF) x=NF;for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) a[$i]++} 
END{x=x/2;for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++) if (x==a[i]) print i}' INPUT_FILE
```

Comment: No worries. :) You can pipe the result to `sort -n` to get it in order.

Comment: Updated the solution so that you have two choices to get the output in order. :) Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Your example works with just a simple;

```
awk '{if($2==$4 && $2==$6 && $2==$8 && $2==$10 && $2==$12 && $2==$14 && $2==$16) print $1}' test.txt | sort -n
```

Any other requirements I'm missing?

EDIT: Apparently with the missing columns you added :) Try

```
awk '{if(NF>1) { found=1; for(i=4; i<NF+1; i+=2) { if($2!=$i) { found=0; } } } if(found) print $1}' test.txt | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

In your input data row # 9 doesn't have all even columns same so not sure how you show 9 in your desired output. You can try following awk command to print 1st col for your task:

```
awk '{same=0; prev=-1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {if (prev != -1 && prev != $i) {same=1; break;} else prev=$i;} if (same==0) print $1;}' awk '{same=0; prev=-1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {if (prev != -1 && prev != $i) {same=1; break;} else prev=$i;} if (same==0) print $1;}'
```